# proxy prob!em using simplexml_load_file in php

Tags: php, simplexml

could somebody help me with this issue? 
I need to know in php latitude and longitude from an address.

I was doing:

> $address = urlencode('my address');
>
> $lat_lng =
>   simplexml_load_file("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address={$address}&sensor=false");

but I got this warning:

> Message: simplexml_load_file()
>   [function.simplexml-load-file]:
>   php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo
>   failed: Temporary failure in name
>   resolution

I think I need to configure the proxy so I changed in this way:

> $address = urlencode('my address');
>
> $ch =
>   curl_init("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address={$address}&sensor=false");
>
> curl_setopt($ch,
>   CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
>
> curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY,
>   'my_proxy);
>
> curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT,
>   'my+port');
>
> $lat_lng =
>   simplexml_load_string(curl_exec($ch));
>
> curl_close($ch);

It seems to be blocked when I call `curl_exec`.

Answer (score 1):

Try w/o proxy settings first, it is probably error in proxy configuration.

```
function curl($url){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_close ($ch);
    return curl_exec($ch);
}

$address = urlencode($address);
$data = curl("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=$address&sensor=false"); 
$lat_lng = simplexml_load_string($data);
```

Answer (score 1):

Check your code

```
curl_close ($ch);
```

should be the last line inside the function