# php parse exchange rate feed XML

Tags: php, xml, parsing

I am trying to use the currentcy exchange rate feeds of the European Central Bank (ECB) 
http://www.ecb.int/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml

They have provided documentation on how to parse the xml but none of the options works for me: I checked that  allow_url_fopen=On  is set.

http://www.ecb.int/stats/exchange/eurofxref/html/index.en.html

For instance, I used but it doesn't echo anything and it seems the $XML object is always empty.

```
<?php
    //This is aPHP(5)script example on how eurofxref-daily.xml can be parsed
    //Read eurofxref-daily.xml file in memory
    //For the next command you will need the config option allow_url_fopen=On (default)
    $XML=simplexml_load_file("http://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml");
    //the file is updated daily between 2.15 p.m. and 3.00 p.m. CET

    foreach($XML->Cube->Cube->Cube as $rate){
        //Output the value of 1EUR for a currency code
        echo '1&euro;='.$rate["rate"].' '.$rate["currency"].'<br/>';
        //--------------------------------------------------
        //Here you can add your code for inserting
        //$rate["rate"] and $rate["currency"] into your database
        //--------------------------------------------------
    }
?>
```

Update:

As I am behind proxy at my test environment, I tried this but still I don't get to read the XML:
    function curl($url){
    $ch = curl_init(); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_close ($ch);
    return curl_exec($ch); }

```
$address = urlencode($address); 
$data = curl("http://www.ecb.int/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml");  
$XML = simplexml_load_file($data);

var_dump($XML); -> returns boolean false
```

Please help me. Thanks!

Comment: What does var_dump($XML) say ?

Comment: Do you have error reporting on and what does it say? Are you using PHP5 and is XML support enabled in `php.ini`? Script works from my local computer so could there be a temporal network problem in your or in the bank's end?

Comment: It works on my system. Since you have `allow_url_fopen=On`, try adding `allow_url_include=On`.

Comment: var_dump($XML) says boolean false. I have PHP 5.3.6 on my local setup.  I have also added allow_url_include=On but I am still not getting to read the XML. Could it be possibly because I am behind proxy on my test system?

Comment: How to enable XML support in php.ini? Which parameters control it?

Answer (score 3):

I didn't find any relevant settings in `php.ini`. Check with `phpinfo()` if you have `SimpleXML` support and `cURLsupport` enabled. (You should have them both and especially `SimpleXML` since you're using it and it returns false, it doesn't complain about missing function.)

Proxy might be an issue here. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1366824/php-simplexml-failing-on-localhost) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5498587/proxy-problem-using-simplexml-load-file-in-php) answer. Using [cURL](http://fi.php.net/curl) could be an answer to your problem.

---

Here's one alternative foud [here](http://www.phpfreaks.com/forums/index.php?topic=325042.0).

```
$url = file_get_contents('http://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml');
$xml =  new SimpleXMLElement($url) ;

//file put contents - same as fopen, wrote  and close
//need to output "asXML" - simple xml returns an object based upon the raw xml
file_put_contents(dirname(__FILE__)."/loc.xml", $xml->asXML());

foreach($xml->Cube->Cube->Cube as $rate){
  echo '1&euro;='.$rate["rate"].' '.$rate["currency"].'<br/>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I have it all enabled. I tried cURL but I still don't get to read the XML. I even saved a local copy, and tried $XML = simplexml_load_file('test.xml'); and on var_dump($XML); I still get boolean false. I don't understand.

Comment: @Veni Found one alternative workaround. Don't really know whats the problem here id you can't read even a local file. Are you able to read any xml files? Is your file's encoding correct (the local file is saved as utf8 file, it's not declared only inside the file as utf8 `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`)? I'm quite puzzled...

Comment: Yes, my local file is saved as UTF-8. I don't understand. Obviously it's some local issue with my setup. Any ideas how I can troubleshoot this? Thanks!

Comment: Issue solved. I had to just by-pass my proxy. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Veni Maybe the `cURL` settings weren't correct if bypassing proxy helped. Why didn't it work locally? Were the proxy in between also in local setup? Anyway, glad that everything works.

Answer (score 0):

This solution works for me:

```
$data = [];

$url = "http://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-hist-90d.xml";
$xmlRaw = file_get_contents($url);

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = FALSE;

$doc->loadXML($xmlRaw);

$node1 = $doc->getElementsByTagName('Cube')->item(0);
foreach ($node1->childNodes as $node2) {
    $value = [];

    foreach ($node2->childNodes as $node3) {
        $value['date'] = $node2->getAttribute('time');
        $value['currency'] = $node3->getAttribute('currency');
        $value['rate'] = $node3->getAttribute('rate');

        $data[] = $value;
        unset($value);
    }
}

echo "<pre"> . print_r($data) . "</pre>";
```

Comment: and btw link fortunately works with http (doesn't redirect to https) so you don't need to worry about curl settings etc. about ssl