# using preg_match from XML feed

Tags: php, xml, preg-match

I'm trying to get the hang of preg_match but I'm having trouble selecting what I want with regex.

I'm using an XML feed found herehttp://www.ecb.int/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml

I want to find a currency and it's value. It's printing as an array, so I'm confused how to do this. Do I need to loop somehow? Even if I do I still haven't figured out the preg_match part.

```
<?
$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://www.ecb.int/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml');
//print_r($xml);

preg_match('/ USD \= \(([0-9\.\,]+)\)$/',$xml,$match);

echo $match[1];
echo $match[2];

?>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

**edit - I tried to get the example on PHP's site to work using my link but I got a bunch of errors. Here's what I have**

```
<?

$string = simplexml_load_file('http://www.ecb.int/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml');

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($string);

$result = $xml->xpath('b/c');

while(list( , $node) = each($result)) {
   echo 'b/c: ',$node,"\n";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using SimpleXML library, so you can use [xpath function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php)

Easier solution is to follow ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10281849/php-parse-exchange-rate-feed-xml)) description:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://www.ecb.int/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml');

foreach($xml->Cube->Cube->Cube as $rate){
  if ($rate["currency"] == 'WANTED CURRENCY') {
    echo $rate["rate"].' '.$rate["currency"].'<br/>';
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you mind looking at my updates. I cant seem to get it to work even using code from PHP's website

Comment: @user1406951 Please look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10281849/php-parse-exchange-rate-feed-xml - first answer will solve your problem :)

Comment: Great, that helped some at least getting it to output, but I still want to be able to preg_match for just one currency.

Comment: Thanks, that was a lot easier than I thought it would be. I tend to over-complicate things. I was thinking I'd have to preg_match it, but I forgot it was just being looped for the output so it could be matched as a string.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use regex, could you try this expression?

```
USD' rate='(.*)'
```

I like to use this website when to help me with my expressions:
http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

In this case I got the contents of the xml with a file_get_contents, pasted them in the box in this site and started making the expression using the bar at the top of the page. As you type, you automatically see if you have any matches in the box below.

Comment: I'm kind of confused with the link you provided. I understand what you said about copying the contents in, but I don't get what the flags, captured groupings and so on mean.

Comment: Oh, after you paste the xml in, you click on the white bar at the top(below 'match') and you start typing your expression. It's really to help you visualise it on the fly. For example for your xml I typed USD' rate=' and I saw that it worked. I added a capture group using () and closed it with a '. That's all you need. Now you go to the bottom and look for 'RegExp:' (it's the first in the list)You copy everything between the slashes. That's your expression for the function.

Comment: Hmm, it wasn't working in chrome for some reason. I opened it in firefox and it started working. No wonder why I was so confused.

Comment: That's strange. I'm using it on chrome.

Comment: When you typed USD' rate='(.*)' into the match box, did USD [rate] => 1.2546  highlight in the main area? I typed in exactly what you have and it's not highlighting it. When I type USD' it highlights that, but as soon as I type anything else it un-highlights.

Comment: We've used a different set of data. Let me check it with the method you used and I'll get back to you.